# Migration failed after changing User ID to UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed my user id to UUID and modified a few tables related to user_id. However for some table like stream, I get the following error. Does anyone knows how to go around please?

```
-- change_column(:streams, :user_id, :string)
   (18.1ms)  ALTER TABLE "streams" ALTER COLUMN "user_id" TYPE character varying
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
   (1.3ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(740533580701532625)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  foreign key constraint "fk_rails_bb64178f90" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "user_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and bigint.
: ALTER TABLE "streams" ALTER COLUMN "user_id" TYPE character varying
```

Comment: hey @muistooshort, what function to call to drop the fk please? in the case of Stream for example. And how to add them back please (Sorry if this is too basic)

Answer (score 2):

The following steps helped fixing the issue:

```
class ConvertTableWithUserToString < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :uuid, :uuid, default: "gen_random_uuid()", null: false
    remove_foreign_key :streams, column: :user_id
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.remove :id
      t.rename :uuid, :id
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
    change_column :streams, :user_id, :string
  end
end
```